# How to high-perform big dataset transformations in Azure?

Tags: performance, azure, bigdata, batch-processing

### Goal / Problem

since 3 weeks we are trying to find the best possible **high-performing** solution in Azure for loading 10 million records (could be even more!) in a staging area, do different transformations based on the staged records and finally store the updates physically in a store again.

To achieve this we did a lot of research and tried different approaches to get the results back in a decent amount of time (below 1 minute max), but we completely got stuck! Every second we can save is a huge benefit for our customer!

Note: We have a huge budget to solve this problem, so the cost-factor can be ignored.

### Example of the input schema

```
+------+--------+----------+
|  Id  |  Year  |  Amount  |
+------+--------+----------+
|  1   |  1900  |     1000 |
|  2   |  1900  |     2000 |
|  3   |  1901  |     4000 |
|  4   |  1902  |     8000 |
|  ... |  ...   |      ... |
|  1M  |  9999  |     1000 |
+------+--------+----------+
```

### Transformation

The transformation process is split in separate steps. Each step has to temporary store its results until we persist the data into a physical store. It has to be possible to rearrange the steps in a different order or just skip a step to create some kind of a workflow.

A **step** could be one of the following:

- Double the `Amount`
- Substract 1k from `Amount`
- Cap the `Amount` to a maximum of 5k
- Cap the `Amount` to a minimum of zero
- Cap the sum of a `Year` to a maximum of 100k

There are so many possible solutions and opportunities in Azure, that it is really hard to know which way is the best to go, so we need help from you.

### What data stores we already considered

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure CosmosDB

### What services we already considered

- Azure Data Factory
- Azure Functions with a self-implemented Fanout/Fanin architecture (vis ServiceBus Queues and Redis Cache)
- Durable Functions
- Azure Databricks

### Question

Is there anyone who had a similar problem to solve and could give us some advices or recommendations for an architecture? We would be really thankful.

*Edit #1: Description of transformation process added*

Comment: What are the "transformations"? Can they be done/expressed with SQL or custom-code is needed? Does they "persistent" across time or you make new "kind of transformation" every time? May be you don't need upload data into Azure, but instead use some kind of csv-file manipulations on-premises, using self-written program/code?

Comment: 10 million records in what format? Maybe azure data lake analytics is a good fit. Or azure data factory. But yes, please post the kind of transformations we are talking about.

Comment: I added some transformation examples. The input and output data should be stored in a SQL Server table. For everything in between we have the freedom to choose whatever makes sense to use as an intermediate storage in terms of increasing the speed of processing.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is really broad. And there are so many variables at play: how (and where) your data gets loaded into Azure, where the data needs to end up, how long it currently takes, where the bottlenecks currently are... Also, there's options for modifying data as it arrives, in a streaming fashion (via Spark, Stream Analytics, Azure Functions...). So many different approaches, and there's simply no "right" way to do this. And stating that you want 1M+ records transformed in under a minute...impossible to know until you benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I know my question was not really clear, because we have no restrictions in choosing where to store the data (sql tables, csv, ...) and which technology/plattform we will compute on (hadoop, databricks/sparks, SQL DWH).  I leave this question open and will give a feedback, when we have found a good solution for ourselves.